# Cannot save email in React.js + Express

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

So I have a function `getProfile()`. Inside it I am trying to fetch users from the server using a POST call, however it's throwing a `CORS` error in its response.

Here is the getProfile:

```js
const getProfile = async () => {
  try {
    const res = await fetch("http://localhost:5000/dashboard/", {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        jwt_token: localStorage.token,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Accept: "application/json",
      },
    });

    const parseData = await res.json();
    setEmail(parseData.email);
    console.log("Try success");
    console.log(parseData.email);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log("Try failed");
    console.error(err.message);
  }
};
```

Comment: what are you getting in `res`   > `console.log(res)` ?

Comment: Well i get this 
Response {type: 'cors', url: 'http://localhost:5000/dashboard/', redirected: false, status: 404, ok: false, …}
body: (...)
bodyUsed: true
headers: Headers {}
ok: false
redirected: false
status: 404
statusText: "Not Found"
type: "cors"
url: "http://localhost:5000/dashboard/"
[[Prototype]]: Response

Comment: here >  clearly you are not getting response from server for your POST call , you need check your backend CORS error

Answer (score 0):

if you are handling your nodeServer by your own you need to add CORS package
please check this and follow their docs
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

1.install package
2. in your app.js file add following

```
var cors = require('cors')
app.use(cors())
```

and change you frontend function `getProfile()` to following:

```
const getProfile = async () => {
    let token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    const myHeaders = new Headers();
    myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/json");
    myHeaders.append("Authorization", "bearer" + token);
    try {
      await fetch("http://localhost:5000/dashboard/", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: myHeaders,
      })
        .then((r) => r.json().then((data) => ({ status: r.status, data })))
        .then((obj) => obj.status === 200 && console.log("data", obj.data));
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Try failed", err.message);
    }
  };
```

Comment: Cors is installed, but cors gives me the code 403 forbidden now, any ideas? Do you need more of my code?

Comment: if you are not sending any payload with your POST request why not use GET ? yes can you share your backend code too ?

Comment: after installing your CORS package did you restarted your nodeServer if not using nodemon ?

Comment: check my updated function for frontend > getProfile()

Comment: your data will reflect >  `console.log("data", obj.data))` you can replace it with `setEmail(obj.data.email);`